# Posting on the UI thread from a singleton manager class

Tags: android, thread-safety, singleton, handler, ui-thread

I have a singleton manager class that is called from Activities (UI thread), then it operates on a different thread (Network) and in the it end should call a callback method in the calling Activity.

I was wondering what is the best way to call the callback methods on the UI thread.
I an familiar with the options (see http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

So I was thinking of two options:

**the first:**
The calling Activities will implement an Interface with a getActivity() method. that method will be used to call Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable).

**the second:**
MainApplication, which inits the manager singleton, will pass a Handler instance that belongs to the UI thread.

What is the better option? 
I'm also happy to hear any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what option you choose, you have to keep in mind that the activities have a certain lifecycle, and unlike your singleton class can be finished or moved to the background. In light of this, you should consider again whether singleton is really the best choice here: if it needs to interact with an activity, maybe the activity should manage its lifecycle. If it doesn't depend on any particular activity, you might want to make it a service and send out broadcasts to notify about progress, etc.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The manager provides a service, technically anyone can call it.
Also, being a singleton it will remain alive as long as the app was not kliled.
And the activities do manage their lifecycles as they register and unregister as listeners in the manager.

Comment: In that case calling an activity interface method should be the better idea. The activity can then decide what exactly to do and whether it needs to run stuff on the UI thread or not.

Comment: in my app, the activity only runs operations on the UI thread. all of the actions that requiere different threads are ran by the manager. so there is no benefit in letting the Activity decide on such things.
considering this, do you still think it is better to use the getActivity() option?

Comment: The activity should still decide what exactly to do and you manager class is not supposed to know about the UI thread and other implementation details. Its responsibility is to do something and deliver the results to the components that care about it. In you case those are activities, but they might as well be services that write things to disk, or send it over the network, or whatever. As long you are talking to a well-defined interface, you (i.e., the manager class) shouldn't know or care about what happens next.